# Failure to write output of shell command to file in Go

Tags: shell, go, exec

I have written the following function for executing the `snt2cooc` command (one of the preprocessing steps for running [GIZA++](http://www.statmt.org/moses/giza/GIZA++.html). For our purposes I think we can consider the `snt2cooc` script to be a black box):

```
func SNTToCOOC(srcVocab, tgtVocab, sntPath, outpath string) error {
    // open the out file for writing
    outfile, err := os.Create(outpath)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer outfile.Close()

    cmdStr := "snt2cooc"
    args := []string{srcVocab, tgtVocab, sntPath}
    cmd := exec.Command(cmdStr, args...)
    cmd.Stdout = outfile
    if err = cmd.Run(); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    cmd.Wait()
    return err
}
```

When running, the function executes without an error, but the output file is empty. This same code works for other similar commands, but not for this specific `snt2cooc` command, and I noticed that when I run this command in the shell directly:

snt2cooc file1.vcb file2.vcb file3.snt

I get the following output:

```
END.
0 2
0 3
0 4
0 5
0 6
```

(truncated for brevity)

And if I send the output of the command to a file directly from the shell:

```
snt2cooc file1.vcb file2.vcb file3.snt > out.txt
```

The contents of `out.txt` are as expected:

```
0 2
0 3
0 4
0 5
0 6
```

Notice how in the first case, the line `END.` is output to stdout first, and only then is the real output of the command sent to stdout. I therefore think there is a race condition going on, where the Go code finishes executing before the command's final output is written to file. This despite calling `cmd.Wait()`. I'm not too sure what exactly the `snt2cooc` command is doing internally. Could someone provide a hint on how to solve this?

**Edit 1:**

It seems like the following code, with the sleep of 500ms included, consistently writes output to the file for the `snt2cooc` command:

```
cmdStr := "snt2cooc"
args := []string{srcVocab, tgtVocab, sntPath}
cmd := exec.Command(cmdStr, args...)
stdout, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
time.Sleep(500 * time.Millisecond)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
err = cmd.Start()
if err != nil {
    return err
}

out := bufio.NewScanner(stdout)
for out.Scan() {
    outfile.Write(out.Bytes())
    outfile.WriteString("\n")
}
if err := out.Err(); err != nil {
    return err
}
```

This proves to me that there is some race condition going on, with the Go program exiting before all output is written to file. I added a bounty to this question, with the hope that someone can 1) explain why this is happening and 2) provide a non-hacky way (i.e. 500ms sleep) to fix it.

Comment: Have you tried calling [`Sync`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.Sync) after running but before closing the file?

Comment: @Ainar-G I tried it now, and it does not seem to have an effect.

Comment: And `Sync` doesn't return any errors either? If you set a `bytes.Buffer` as stdout, and then print the buffer's contents after running, is it empty as well?

Comment: No error from `Sync`. If I set `bytes.Buffer` as stdout, it's still empty the majority of the time, yes. One out of 20 or 30 times it has something, but this is also the case when writing to file (without the timeout--with the timeout it always writes it, but I'm not sure if it would continue if the script were to take more than 500ms to execute, or if the output would always be complete)

Comment: Then I don't have any other guesses besides checking the error returned by `cmd.Wait` and trying to do the same in e.g. Python to see if the issue is Go-specific. Sorry.

Comment: @Ainar-G Thanks! Trying the same thing in Python is a good idea - so far I've only tested that it works consistently from the shell (it does). That should shed some light on what's going on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, clean up your code.

`cmd.Stderr = os.DevNull`, so you ignore stderr. Stdout and Stderr specify the process's standard output and error. If either is nil, Run connects the corresponding file descriptor to the null device (os.DevNull).

`cmd.Wait()` returns `error,` you ignore it. `func (c *Cmd) Wait() error`.

`Wait` waits for the command to exit. It must have been started by `Start.` You use `Run,` not `Start.`

What output do you get when you run this code?

`failure.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    err := SNTToCOOC("file1.vcb", "file2.vcb", "file3.snt", "out.txt")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}

func SNTToCOOC(srcVocab, tgtVocab, sntPath, outpath string) error {
    outfile, err := os.Create(outpath)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer outfile.Close()
    cmdStr := "snt2cooc"
    args := []string{srcVocab, tgtVocab, sntPath}
    cmd := exec.Command(cmdStr, args...)
    cmd.Stdout = outfile
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
    err = cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return err
}
```

Run:

```
$ rm -f out.txt && go run failure.go && cat out.txt
```

Also, what output do you get when you run this code with `cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout` substituting for `cmd.Stdout = outfile`.

Comment: Thanks, this led me to discovering the real problem, which was in a function called before `SNTToCooc`--the one which generates `file3.snt`--I was using `cmd.Start()` there instead of `cmd.Run()`, so it wasn't finished before `snt2cooc` was called, and so `snt2cooc` was working with an empty input file. Of course, by the time I check from the shell, all the files (except snt2cooc's) have content, so that's why I didn't notice. My apologies for framing the question too narrowly to have been able to spot that, but thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1):

The problem isn't with the innard of `SNTtoCooc` but how you write to the file itself using `cmd.Stdout`:

```
func anyWrite(args []string, outpath string) error {
        outfile, err := os.Create(outpath)
        if err != nil {
                return err
        }

        defer outfile.Close()

        // I use simple "echo" here
        cmd := exec.Command("echo", args...)
        stdout, err := cmd.Output()
        if err != nil {
                return err
        }

        // Use this instead of cmd.Stdout seems to solve the problem
        outfile.Write(stdout)

        return nil
}

func main() {
        args := []string{"Line 1", "Line 2", "Line 3"}
        if err := anyWrite(args, "./outfile.txt"); err != nil {
                panic(err) 
        }
}
```

As per the [comments](https://golang.org/src/os/exec/exec.go?s=844:3484#L28) in `os/exec`

> Stdout and Stderr specify the process's standard output and error. If
>   either is nil, Run connects the corresponding file descriptor to the
>   null device (os.DevNull).

Comment: If I run your example as is, it reports `exec: already started` (`cmd.Output()` runs the command, a second `cmd.Run()` is not necessary). Even so, after removing the `cmd.Run()` part, with the `echo` command it writes the arguments to file, but with the `snt2cooc` command there is no output in the file. So it still seems to me like it does indeed have something to do `snt2cooc` command itself.

Comment: You're right thanks for correcting. Have you tried using `cmd.Start()` with `cmd.Wait()`  before writing to the file?

Comment: Yeah, I just tried using `cmd.Start()` and then `cmd.Wait()`, but no luck. It seems like `snt2cooc` is writing to stdout in a different thread from the main thread, maybe?

Comment: Try debugging the race condition? https://golang.org/doc/articles/race_detector.html

Comment: Good idea, but unfortunately the race detector doesn't pick up anything. I have meanwhile confirmed that using `stdout, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()` and adding `time.Sleep(500 * time.Millisecond)` after that line consistently writes output to the file. The question is just whether this will still work if the command takes longer than 500ms to run...